# Using express JS and Vue.js in electron Framework

Tags: express, vue.js, electron

Is it possible to use Vue.js and express JS simultaneously in an project having electron JS? How is that possible? I have a project which is already running in Vue.js and electron JS but how do I implement express JS in current project?

Comment: it does not make much sense to implement express with electron. renderer and main process should communicate using ipcMain and ipcRenderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
let express = require('./express') // Your express app
```

https://gist.github.com/maximilian-lindsey/a446a7ee87838a62099d

To add express in your project  and you can use `electron-vue`.

Boilerplate to add vue to you project: https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue